# Batteries in series capacity considerations

Tags: current, series, batteries

Let´s say I have a 2 AA 1,5V 1000mAh Alkaline battery cells in series.

The circuit it´s connected to consumes 500mA, works at 3V and it´s powered on always, and taking into account other electrical specs as ideal, the time it would take to last would be:

1000mAh / 500mA = 2h

Is this correct?

I´ve checked [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196300/why-do-series-combinations-of-batteries-not-increase-capacity) question and it confuses me.

Comment: Calculate the watt-hours (Wh).

Comment: Are you likely to get both in AA sizes?

Comment: Add the datasheet of the specific batteries concerned. As Andy is hinting, one is probably lying about its spec. To address the question : if both are honest about their capacity, and used according to their ratings, the answer would be No.

Comment: *Two AA 1,5V 1000mAh Alkaline batteries connected in series* Making that a 1,5 V + 1,5 V = 3 V battery. Connecting in series doesn't affect the current so it remains 1000 mAh. So basically you're asking if 1 liter of fuel lasts as long as two times halve a litre of the same fuel.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. This is a theoretical question, not based in any datasheet.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie You are right. I'm going to edit the question so that you can understand what I'm asking for

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  I´ve changed the question, hope it makes sense now. Thank you

Comment: `1000mAh / 500mA = 2h` Ideally yes, however the voltage will change (rapidly) as the battery capacity decreases, making current consumption go up (if there is a regulator there demanding 3V). Even if you don't have a regulator, you won't be able to drain the battery all the way to 0, your actual runtime will be closer to 1 hour. [Check this other question for details](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141812/max-discharge-rate-of-alkaline-aa-batteries).

Comment: "mA-h" has units of charge.  "Capacity" here is like "_this_ amount of electrons are stored in this little cylindrical container".  When you connect a path from its terminals, _that many_ electrons flow before the voltage goes to zero.  So the same # of electrons flow even if you have 2 cells in series.  So the mA-h or A-h does not change no matter how many cells are in series.  (What changes is the voltage those electrons "come out at, from the entire series", so to speak.)